# How do I do this with Python list? (itemgetter?)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
[{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}]
```

I want to select whatever in the list that is "id".
Basically, I want to print 44, since that's "id" in the list.

Comment: If there's always just one key in each elem, you're better off using tuples.

Comment: What Torsten suggests not only makes sense, but it also simplifies the problem, because having this: `L = [('id', 44), ('name', 'alexa'), ('color', 'blue')]`, you can do this: `dict(L)['id']`

Comment: could refine question with editing `is "id"`. because "id", "name" or "color" doesn't resemble object identity of the items, but `is` in python implies a search for object identity. even if I gather that you didn't mean this sense of 'is', the question does not seem overly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is the best solution:

```
>>> L = [{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}]

>>> newd = {}
>>> for d in L:
...    newd.update(d)
>>> newd['id']
44
```

Comment: Or `newd = dict(tuple(d.items()) for d in L)`

Answer (score 5):

That's a weird data structure... A list of one item dictionaries.

```
key = 'id'
l = [{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}]

print [ x[key] for x in l if key in x ][0]
```

Assuming you can rely on key being present precisely once...

Maybe you should just convert the list into a dictionary first:

```
key = 'id'
l = [{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}]

d = {}
for x in l:
    d.update(x)
print d[key]
```

Comment: Perhaps because it answers the question? has_key http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key
Deprecated, but still works...

Comment: has been deprecated for 4.5 years, and of course it doesn't even exist in py3k. So, I don't think that it'd qualify as *still works*.

Comment: I wonder why `has_key` doesn't trigger a deprecation warning in 2.6 :(

Answer (score 4):

All the other answers solve your problem, I am just suggesting an alternative way of going about doing this.

Instead of having a `list` of `dict`s where you query on the key and have to iterate over all `list` items to get values, just use a `dict` of `list`s. Each key would map to a `list` of values (or just one value if all your `dict`s had distinct sets of keys).

So,

```
data=[{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}]
```

becomes

```
data={'id':[44], 'name':['alexa'], 'color':['blue']}
```

and you can neatly access the value for `'id'` using `data['id']` (or `data['id'][0]` if you only need one value).

If all your keys are distinct across the `dict`s (as in your example) you don't even have to have `list`s of values.

```
data={'id':44, 'name':'alexa', 'color':'blue'}
```

Not only does this make your code cleaner, it also speeds up your queries which no longer have to iterate over a `list`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> KEY = 'id'
>>>
>>> my_list = [{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}]
>>> my_ids = [x[KEY] for x in my_list if KEY in x]
>>> print my_ids
[44]
```

Which is obviously a list of the values you want. You can then print them as required.

Answer (score 2):

```
 >>> from itertools import dropwhile
 >>> def find_value(l, key):
 ...    return dropwhile(lambda x: key not in x, l).next()[key]
 >>> find_value([{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}], "id")
```

This will do a linear search, but only until the element is found.

If you want to have proper error handling, use:

```
def find_value(l, key):
    try:
        return dropwhile(lambda x: key not in x, l).next()[key]
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError(key)
```

Comment: Instead of using generator.next(), you can use next(generator,def_val). The latter method will return a def_val when StopIteration is reached, so you don't need to wrap it up in a try\catch block.

Comment: But then you'd have to check the default value, since not finding the element is exception---unless the function should be extended to include a default value, too. Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [{'id':44}, {'name':'alexa'},{'color':'blue'}]
>>> newd=dict(d.items()[0] for d in L)
>>> newd['id']
44
```